# What are the various options I have for a faulty disk?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

**To know :**
What all things can I try myself to recover data? (Can I open the disk and do something myself with the hope of fixing?  I know data recovery centers are possible, but they are very expensive.)

**Disk :** 
The disk inside Seagate 3 TB External (STBV3000100).  I took out the disk and used as internal.

**Issue :** 
Hard disk not working.

**Diagnosis so far :**
Since this was supposed to be used as external disk, and I ran it almost 24*7 for a month or more, the motor has failed.  I hear squeeky sound at boot up, as if the motor is not able to start rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Hard disks are assembled in a clean room environment - one that is entirely dust free.  This is because any small particles floating around inside the container can cause damage.

It is unlikely that you would be able to create a clean enough environment in a domestic or office environment.

This effectively eliminates any useful DIY remedies.  Your options are to use a professional data recovery service, or throw away the disk, get a new one and restore from backup.